# linux command executed from a different path than whereis

Tags: linux, bash

I installed [paris-traceroute](https://code.google.com/p/paris-traceroute/) and I don't remember what I did to replace the ping packaged with Ubuntu Trusty with paris-ping, which requires root to run. Now I want to get rid of it.

```
$ ping --version
version 1.0

$ whereis ping
ping: /bin/ping /usr/share/man/man8/ping.8.gz

$ ping
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ping: No such file or directory
```

`paris-ping` was at `/usr/local/bin/ping`. I deleted that file but now the `ping` command still does not run from `/bin/ping`.  What I am missing here?

Comment: It somehow fixed itself after updating $PATH and several logout/logins. Still not sure why it was behaving that way tho

Answer (score 6):

It's because you haven't started a new shell since you deleted the binary.

Use that command to reload the locations of the binaries:

```
hash -r
```

Or just restart the shell.

Comment: Looks like updating $PATH will automatically trigger rehash. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command

Comment: Yes, but you haven't changed the `$PATH` variable (except when you made a relogin/restart of the shell). You just deleted a binary that was hashed before. Thats why the error came